# Multiple conditional output from single input

Tags: awk

I am having a file test.txt. I am looking for multiple pattern matching and I am printing them independently one by one with

```
    awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /ccc/ { print $0 }' test.txt >test1.txt
    awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /abb/ { print $0 }' test.txt >test2.txt
    awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /abc/ { print $0 }' test.txt >test3.txt
```

Now, can I run it in one go. Like after

```
    awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /ccc/ { print $0 }' test.txt
```

in the lines which dont match the above pattern can I run

```
    awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /abb/ { print $0 }'
```

and similarly in unmatched pattern lines

```
    awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /abc/ { print $0 }'
```

Input file test.txt

```
   NNNNNabcabAAAAATCTAATCTGCCAGTT
   NNNNNabcccTTTTTCTAGTCACGATAGCC
   NNNNNaaabbCTAGTTTGTGTAGTAATTTT
   NNNNNaaaabTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
   NNNNNabbbbTTTTTTCACTACTGGGTTTC
   NNNNNabcaaTTTTTTTTAATGGGTCTCAA
   NNNNNabaccTTTTTTTTTCGGGAGGCGGG
   NNNNNccaaaTTTTTTTTTTTTTATTTGAG
   NNNNNabcccTTTTTTTTTACACACAATTC
   NNNNNabcccTAAGACTGGCCCACAGCTGA
   NNNNNabcaaTAGAGACGGGGTTTCACCAT
   NNNNNabcaaTTTTTGTCGAAGATCTCACC
   NNNNNabcabTTGGTAAACAGGCGGGTGTA
   NNNNNabcccTACTTTTTTTAGTGATACAC
   NNNNNaaabbTTTTTGCAAAAAGTAATTTG
   NNNNNabcabTTTTTTTTTCTTTCTGCCTG
   NNNNNabcaaTTTTGAGACAGAATCTTGCT
   NNNNNaaabbTTTTTTTTTTTTTACTAGTG
   NNNNNabcccTAGACAGGGAATACTTTATT
   NNNNNabcabGACAGGGAATACTTATATTC
```

awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /ccc/ { print $0 }' test.txt >test1.txt

test1.txt

```
NNNNNabcccTTTTTCTAGTCACGATAGCC
NNNNNabcccTTTTTTTTTACACACAATTC
NNNNNabcccTAAGACTGGCCCACAGCTGA
NNNNNabcccTACTTTTTTTAGTGATACAC
NNNNNabcccTAGACAGGGAATACTTTATT
```

awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /abb/ { print $0 }' test.txt >test2.txt

test2.txt

```
NNNNNaaabbCTAGTTTGTGTAGTAATTTT
NNNNNabbbbTTTTTTCACTACTGGGTTTC
NNNNNaaabbTTTTTGCAAAAAGTAATTTG
NNNNNaaabbTTTTTTTTTTTTTACTAGTG
```

awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /abc/ { print $0 }' test.txt >test3.txt

```
NNNNNabcabAAAAATCTAATCTGCCAGTT
NNNNNabcccTTTTTCTAGTCACGATAGCC
NNNNNabcaaTTTTTTTTAATGGGTCTCAA
NNNNNabcccTTTTTTTTTACACACAATTC
NNNNNabcccTAAGACTGGCCCACAGCTGA
NNNNNabcaaTAGAGACGGGGTTTCACCAT
NNNNNabcaaTTTTTGTCGAAGATCTCACC
NNNNNabcabTTGGTAAACAGGCGGGTGTA
NNNNNabcccTACTTTTTTTAGTGATACAC
NNNNNabcabTTTTTTTTTCTTTCTGCCTG
NNNNNabcaaTTTTGAGACAGAATCTTGCT
NNNNNabcccTAGACAGGGAATACTTTATT
NNNNNabcabGACAGGGAATACTTATATTC
```

While doing like this, following lines are in two output files

```
  NNNNNabcccTAAGACTGGCCCACAGCTGA
  NNNNNabcccTACTTTTTTTAGTGATACAC
  NNNNNabcccTAGACAGGGAATACTTTATT
  NNNNNabcccTTTTTCTAGTCACGATAGCC
  NNNNNabcccTTTTTTTTTACACACAATTC
```

What I am looking for is once an output is print, I dont want to look for matching patten in those input files again. My expected output

test1.txt

```
NNNNNabcccTTTTTCTAGTCACGATAGCC
NNNNNabcccTTTTTTTTTACACACAATTC
NNNNNabcccTAAGACTGGCCCACAGCTGA
NNNNNabcccTACTTTTTTTAGTGATACAC
NNNNNabcccTAGACAGGGAATACTTTATT
```

test2.txt

```
NNNNNaaabbCTAGTTTGTGTAGTAATTTT
NNNNNabbbbTTTTTTCACTACTGGGTTTC
NNNNNaaabbTTTTTGCAAAAAGTAATTTG
NNNNNaaabbTTTTTTTTTTTTTACTAGTG
```

test3.txt

```
NNNNNabcabAAAAATCTAATCTGCCAGTT
NNNNNabcaaTTTTTTTTAATGGGTCTCAA
NNNNNabcaaTAGAGACGGGGTTTCACCAT
NNNNNabcaaTTTTTGTCGAAGATCTCACC
NNNNNabcabTTGGTAAACAGGCGGGTGTA
NNNNNabcabTTTTTTTTTCTTTCTGCCTG
NNNNNabcaaTTTTGAGACAGAATCTTGCT
NNNNNabcabGACAGGGAATACTTATATTC
```

Comment: @Ed Morton Oh I see while posting I missed initial 5 Ns. I am correcting it. The initial N can varies from 5 Ns to 15 Ns

Comment: Why bother with the substr() when the chars you care about only appear in that location or nowhere? With 5 leading Ns the first position after that is 6 btw, not 5, so if you do want to use substr() for some reason then it'd be `substr($1,6.whatever)` rather than `substr($1,5.whatever)` and from the data you posted `whatever` would be 5 rather than 15. Again - [edit] your question to show the expected output given that input to make it a complete [mcve].

Comment: Wait - the initial N can vary from 5 to 15 Ns? OK then **SHOW** that in your example. To get a good solution make sure the sample input/output you provide covers your real use cases not just one sunny day scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do all three in one awk process, try:

```
awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /ccc/ { print>"test1.txt"}
    substr($1,5,15) ~ /abb/ { print>"test2.txt"}
    substr($1,5,15) ~ /abc/ { print>"test3.txt"}' test.txt
```

Here, `print>"test1.txt"` prints to file `test1.txt`.

Note that `>` means something different in awk than it means in `shell`.  In `awk`, like in `shell`, the first `print` to a file will *overwrite* the previous contents of the file.  However, unlike shell, subsequent awk `print` statements using `>` *append* to the file.

#### Variation:  Printing only to the first matched output file

```
awk 'substr($1,5,15) ~ /ccc/ { print>"test1.txt"; next}
    substr($1,5,15) ~ /abb/ { print>"test2.txt"; next}
    substr($1,5,15) ~ /abc/ { print>"test3.txt"}' test.txt
```

Here, when a match is found, `next` tells awk to skip the rest of the tests and jump to start over on the next line.

Comment: This will not do what the OP asked for `...in the lines which dont match the above pattern can I run...` - instead of just doing the 2nd op if the first RE didn't match this will call substring 3 times for every input line which is inefficient but, more importantly, given an input line that matches all 3 regexps will print to all 3 output files instead of just printing to the first matching file.

Comment: @John1024: If I want to restrict the matching pattern to single match; like if the pattern matching once I dont want to search the match for those input lines for other pattern; is there a way to do it?

Comment: @user3377241 Yes and you already have the way to efficiently do that posted, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56069986/1745001. Didn't you try the posted solutions before accepting one?

Comment: @Ed Morton: I was about to post to your response: there I am finding a syntax error at source line 5
 context is
     if      (str~ /abc/ >>> 
 <<<

Since I am working on mac, before posting it I wanter to try it on a linux machine.

Comment: Then you copy/pasted wrong or you took a copy before I had fixed an issue that ogusizmail pointed out. Try it again. if I ever post code that will only work in some awks rather than all awks then I state which awks it works on and why. That code will work in any awk.

Comment: @user3377241 Yes, that can be done.  I just added to the answer code restrict to a single match.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '
{
    str = substr($1,5,15)
    out = 0
    if      (str ~ /ccc/) out=1
    else if (str ~ /abb/) out=2
    else if (str ~ /abc/) out=3
}
out { print > ("test" out ".txt") }
' test.txt
```

With GNU awk you could use a switch statement instead of nested `if`s.

Comment: @oguzismail That's what happens when the OP doesn't provide sample input/output - we have nothing to test against so the posted scripts are untested and potentially buggy. I just fixed that, thx, but it's still untested of course so there could be other issues. I **REALLY** wish we had a question template with boxes for "Sample Input", "Expected Output", "What You've Tried", "What Problems Did You Experience" and "What Is Your Question"!

Comment: here my main questing was can I merge two awk command into one; so did not feel the need of the template file. Will add it from next time.

Comment: @user3377241 Can you provide sample data? I have the feeling the awk program could be simplified when we know the input text's format

Comment: @hek2mgl my apologies for this. I have added the sample data

Comment: @user3377241 sample input is half of the data we're looking for so that's a good start, now add the expected output given that input and THAT will make it a complete question.

Answer (score 0):

This golf presumes no concurrent matches.

```
gawk '{
  match(substr($1,5,15), /(ccc)|(abb)|(abc)/, A)   # probably unnecessary substring
  for(i in A) n=i                                  # get last index of A (match number)
  print > "test" n ".txt"                          # print to variable filename
}' test.txt
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), and you'll get a syntax error in some awks due to the unparenthesized right side of output redirection, and since `in` loops are random the output won't necessarily go to the file for the first of the listed regexps to match, e.g. a string like `cccabbabc` could be written to any of the 3 output files depending on what order awk decides to visit the indices with `in`. See the gawk man page for `sorted_in` for one solution to that.

Comment: FWIW I'd just do `n=0; for(i=1; i<=3; i++) if (i in A) { n=i; break }`. You still need to handle the case where none of the regexps match and nothing gets printed.

Comment: Oh, hang on, now I understand - THAT'S what you meant by `presumes no concurrent matches`. Got it. I'll leave the comments in case they're useful if it turns out that concurrent matches are possible after all.

Comment: What's the cleanest way to get the numbers of the matched capture groups?

Comment: `gawk '{match($0, /(a)|(b)|(c)/, a); for(i in a) print i, a[i]}' <<< bcaabcbacbabc`

Comment: Well, the two problems with `for (i in A)` to get the indices for an array populated by match() are a) the order of `in` is random, and b) you'll get the metadata too (i.e. the indices of the start and length of the whole regexp and each matching RE segment). It depends what you want out. To only see the indices and values populated by the regexp would be `for(i in a) if (i == i+0) print i, a[i]`.

Comment: How can it possibly be random? Do you mean it's unspecified or arbitrary?

Comment: However you want to phrase "not in any specific order related to it's contents". It's usually the order the values end up stored in the hash table, but it's implementation-dependent. All you can rely on is that whatever order it is at point A in your code, it'll be the same order at point B for the same values.

Comment: To get the indices in numeric order with GNU awk one way is `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc"; for(i in a) if (i == i+0) print i, a[i]`. That includes `a[0]` which matches the whole regexp, you can obviously exclude that.

Comment: Not sure it's clear but with your existing code `for(i in A) n=i` could result in `n` exiting the loop set to `1start` or similar given `A` will contain metadata with indices like `0start, 0length, 1start, 1length` and `in` order is "random".